# Making statistics on database columns through Cursor?

Tags: java, android, statistics, android-cursor

I have a `Cursor` querying a database. I'm interested in getting all numbers from a column, and make some simple statistics on them (e.g., mean, standard deviation and not so much more) which will be shown to the user.

I miss the whole pattern here. Should I store all the values in, say, a `int[]` array and then make operations? The only way that comes to my mind is something like:

```
int entries = cursor.getCount();
int[] array = new int[entries];

for (int i = 0; i < entries; i++) {
    cursor.moveToPosition(i);
    array[i] = cursor.getInt(...);
}
```

And at this point I'm stuck, because I don't know how to perform stuff (be it even a simple mean) on `int[]`, without maybe a second `for`.

As a second chance, I could go like:

```
int entries = cursor.getCount();
float mean = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < entries; i++) {
    cursor.moveToPosition(i);
    int newValue = cursor.getInt(...);
    mean = mean + newValue/entries;
}
return mean;
```

But it keeps looking bad to me. 
Moreover, things could get worse if I need to calculate more complex statistics. Could this for loop be avoided somehow? Is there any more correct way?

Comment: you could probably get the values while querying. Sqlite has the `AVG` function. You should check if it is also available in android (it should).

Comment: @Blackbelt thanks, nice to know. However I will surely need to calculate more than a mean value, and if [these](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html) are all available functions, I'm not really done. I just wonder if `for` + `moveToPosition()` is the standard way.

Comment: well you listed two: mean and standard deviation. The mean is straightforward, you have already the function. To calculate the standard deviance, you can use sum, avg, and count, to calculate the argument of the square root,

Comment: @Blackbelt Might be me knowing nothing about SQLite, but how could I use `SUM( columnName )` on column values, if I need the sum of (value[i]-average)^2? Would something like `SUM((columnName - AVG(columnName))^2)` work? Thank you.

Comment: it's slightly more complicated that just that, but you are on the right track

Comment: @Blackbelt based on other answers I figured out this expression for variance: `SELECT SUM((column - subquery.avg) * (column - subquery.avg)) / (COUNT(column)-1) FROM table, (SELECT AVG(column) AS avg FROM table) AS subquery`. I would ask you 1. if this sounds correct 2. to post an answer so that I can accept it. Thank you.

Comment: yep it should be it.

Comment: were you able to make it works?

Comment: @Blackbelt yes sir. Again, if you answer I'll accept it :)  `c.moveToPosition()` would have been really slow compared to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the function `AVG` of sqlite to calculate the mean. To calculate the `standard deviation`, you can use the function `SUM`, combined with the `AVG`. As you correctly stated in your comment

```
SELECT SUM((column - subquery.avg) * (column - subquery.avg)) / (COUNT(column)-1) 
   FROM table, 
    (SELECT AVG(column) AS avg FROM table) AS subquery
```

should do it